# Android Studio is forcing me to use android.media import rather than google.play FaceDetector

Tags: android, import, face-detection

I am trying to perform an exercise using Google Play's FaceDetector and every time I try to use FaceDetector it imports android.media.  I know I can explicitly call the class by using the full path, but I would rather not have to do that.  Does anyone know of a way for me to fix this so that the appropriate libraries are imported.  Gradle dependency is correct etc.  Thank you.

Gradle Version: 4.4
Android Plugin Version: 3.1.4

app build gradle

```html
ndroid {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.emojify"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2 did the trick and imports are working automatically now. Of course, re-sync after the change, obviously.

I guess the old version of 10 did not have the same paths as that of 15?